# Cookie gives probably wrong format back

Tags: javascript, jquery, js-cookie

In a Laravel application, I use selectpicker for filterst. I like to store the lates status in a cookie.

Save status:

```
        function saveFilterStatus() {
            alert ($('#locationSelect').val())
            Cookies.set('location', $('#locationSelect').val());
        }
```

Result of alert: 31,32,37

Preselect selectpicker:

```
        alert(Cookies.get('location'))
        $('#locationSelect').selectpicker('val', Cookies.get('location'));
```

Result of alert: ["31","32","37"]

If i set `$('#locationSelect').selectpicker('val', ["31","32","37"]);`it works

If i set `$('#locationSelect').selectpicker('val', Cookies.get('location'));`it doesn't work

What i have to adapt or what is missing that `$('#locationSelect').selectpicker('val', Cookies.get('location'));` works?

Comment: You would be better of using localstorage for this instead of cookies

Comment: @LawrenceCherone - how would that help with the problem

Comment: @JaromandaX It would work ;/

Comment: `$('#locationSelect').val()` is an ARRAY of strings ... alerting that will alert the `toString` representation of that Array ... i.e. exactly what you see - but `Cookies.set` handles the Array by either using `JSON.stringify` or `.toSource` method of array (not sure which) so you get the string you see alerted

Comment: @LawrenceCherone would `$('#locationSelect').selectpicker('val', "31,32,37")` work better than `$('#locationSelect').selectpicker('val', ["31","32","37"])` - because localStorage would store `["31","32","37"]` as `"31,32,37"`

Comment: @JaromandaX genrally you stringify the data going in or layer that logic into a method to call, as your right it stores strings, like cookies. What I was getting at in my original comment was its a simple API `localStorage.foo = "bar"`, no lib, no hassle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`js-cookie` plugin stores the cookie value in string representation (Using `JSON.stringify`). When you need to get the array or object in Cookie by using `js-cookie` plugin you need to use the `Cookies.getJSON('keyName')`

So in your case use `Cookies.getJSON('location')`.

Also you can use `JSON.parse(Cookies.get('location'))`

Comment: to clarify `string representation` ... this isn't the result of `array.toString()`, which is what you get with alert ... rather `array.toSource()` or `JSON.stringify(array)`

Comment: js-cookie plugin stores object or array using JSON.stringify method

Comment: OK - I've learned something about a library I never want to use :p